# Transition Matrix with an unknown variable

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes

I have the following transition matrix:

[image]

Using just the information of this matrix is it possible to calculate the value of **a**? Do we find **a** by finding the determinant of P which is equal to 1 ? I am simply throwing out a guess as I am not sure how to tackle this problem.

Comment: What, precisely is a "transition matrix"?  I mean, what  properties does it have that non-transition matrices don't have?

Comment: It's a concept/tool in markov chains. It's a matrix containing probabilities of moving from one state to another in a single time unit. For example, if H= high performance rating and M= Medium performance rating, then the probability of transitioning from H to M is 0.2 and this info can be displayed in a matrix such as the one I've shown in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Markov chain transition matrix must have its rows (or columns, depending on the convention) sum to $1$. If we look at the M row, we have $0.2+1-2\alpha+0.2=1$, which means $\alpha=0.2$.

Comment: My understanding of markov chains are still quite intro-level. This was really quite simple and well explained too, thanks!

Comment: $\alpha = 0.2$ is a necessary condition. We need to check that with this value of $\alpha$, we have as well $1-\alpha-\alpha^2+0.24=0$ which is exact. Happy end...